# Server for an android game

Tags: android, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, server, registration

I'm totally new at this and I have some questions. I wanna create a game which requires signing to a server, so the player can play online. It's a quiz game like (Trivia Crack). Anyway, what kind of server can I use for a game of this type?

Can I use Google app engine or amazon web services?

The game will require the player to register a username, password and an email (like mini clip games on the play store). But where will the players details (username, password and email) be stored? Can I use the same services to store the players details?

What software development kit can be used to create a game like trivia crack quiz game. I mean can I create a game like this by using SDK or I have to use other software?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. I recommend the game engine [jmonkeyengine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.org) that has multiplayer functionality. It's written in Java and I've tried running it on ec2 which worked. I started a java game server on a linux ec2 instance and then I could connect two simple game clients. I would recommend that setup if you want to make a multiplayer game with game clients and a server. More info and exmples are available from this link: http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/jme3:advanced:networking Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I worked for a game company that used google app engine as the server, and Unity3d for the game engine that spit out mobile apps on ios and adroid (client). Your player details will be stored in the datastore if you use app engine. It will basically work like this: Your mobile app will send data (via a post request) to your google app engine server, which will then update the datastore with the player stats you sent it. When your client (unity3d app) needs to retrieve user data, you will ping your app engine server (via a get request) to access the data store and send the data back (as json).

Comment: of course. You can use any server setup you want, as well as any type of database you find most useful for your project.